# OpenCart can't recover password via Email

Tags: opencart

Can't login into OpenCart installed 1 year ago (( 
System informs 'Email not found', but email is located into db.

Answer (score 0):

Run this in phpmyadmin to reset your password.

```
UPDATE `opencart`.`oc_user` SET `password` = MD5('123456') WHERE `oc_user`.`user_id` = 'YOUR_USER_ID';
```

Comment: Thx! I've changed pass. System tells 'Email not found', but I see email into db  (